# CSS: Flex col, ensure that images should fit their parent max-height

Tags: html, css

I know it must be a silly mistake, but I'm not getting the point why the images do not fill their parent max-height? I've tried many variations with max-height, height and etc, but I still do not get the point, what am I missing? :)

```
<div class="flex flex-col gap-5 justify-between max-h-[30rem]">
   <div>
      <img class="h-full w-full object-cover rounded-2xl" src="{{ property_view.image_urls[1] }}" alt="house">
   </div>
   <div>
      <img class="h-full w-full object-cover rounded-2xl" src="{{ property_view.image_urls[1] }}" alt="house">
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, percentage-based `height` or `max-height` doesn't work if the element (`<img>`) is a grandchild of a flex item. A workaround I could find is to add `flex` and `min-h-0` to the container of the `<img>`s:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col gap-5 justify-between max-h-[30rem]">
   <div class="flex min-h-0">
      <img class="w-full max-h-full object-cover rounded-2xl" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg" alt="house">
   </div>
   <div class="flex min-h-0">
      <img class="w-full max-h-full object-cover rounded-2xl" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg" alt="house">
   </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```